# Magento 2 - Duplicating the Shipping Method Section

Tags: orders, shipping, shipping-methods, magento2.3.1

[image]

I am trying to split the order (creating 2 orders) based on product attribute selection which has been done. but now i want to add two separate shipping method section so i can send order with different shipping selection.

Please let me how to override the shipping section

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.2.4 or greater version, there is an option of multishipping.

```
Store > Configuration > Sales > Multishipping Settings Enable - Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses
```

You can try to manage the same by using the Multi address shipping.

Comment: I have tried enabling this configuration but there is no change in checkout